# split char data without delimeter

Tags: c

i have this data

> 27a1bc

thats supposed to be a data recieved from serial communication/uart.
the question is, is there anyway i could separate this data without delimeter? i need the data change to this

```
 27
 a1
 bc
```

is there anyway i could do this without delimeter/strtok?
here is my code, im stuck.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char usart[] = "27a1bc";

int main(void) {
// your code goes here
scanf("%c", usart[1]);
scanf("%c", usart[0]);

return 0; }
```

Comment: is it always 2 chars per string?

Comment: whadya mean? im sorry im new in c, lets say i recieve that data from uart, and i need to make it 3 different data, hows that possible?

Comment: @MukiWahyuJati - you've shown a 6 character string that contains 3 parts. Is the string always 6 characters and is each part always 2 characters? If so, the answer is trivial. Put each set of 2 characters into a new buffer (You may or may not require that it contains space for the 2 chars **and** an additional character to terminate the string), done.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a pointer to an array of 3 `char`'s (2 + 1 for the trailing NUL) and `memcpy` in a loop:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char usart[] = "27a1bc";

int main(void)
{
    size_t i, n = sizeof usart / 2;
    char (*token)[3];

    token = calloc(n, sizeof *token);
    if (token == NULL) {
        perror("calloc");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        memcpy(token[i], usart + (i * 2), 2);
        puts(token[i]);
    }
    free(token);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Isn't `sscanf` a bit of an overkill here ?

Comment: is it stored in an array? i cant find my first, scond, and third data

Comment: @MukiWahyuJati, yes, an array of 3 elements, you can't find them? why not?

Comment: i mean if i want to do add operation between the 27 and a1, what should i call? or if i want to do "if" statement

Comment: is there any variable or char that contain them? something like var 1 = 27 , var 2 = a1 , var 3 = bc